# Run a data profile from my Custom module in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I am trying to run a data profile in custom magento module.
This my Observer in my module where i am trying to run data profile

```
class CP_Model_Observer {

   public function createupdates($schedules) {
       $collection = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile')->getCollection();

       foreach ($collection as $profile) {        

            $userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
            $userModel->setUserId(0);

            Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);

            if (!$profile->getId()) {
            Mage::log('error: ' . $profileId . ' - incorrect profile id', null, $log_file);
            return;
            }

            Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);

            if($profile->run())
            mail($to,$sub,'Mail To Test');

       }
   }
}
```

The rest of the functionality in createupdates() function works and send mail too.
I am trying to run a dataprofile for import.
The problem is with this part only. Dont know much about running data-profiles in modules.

Any Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: hi @tousif...did you solve this?can you give idea for do this stuff?